# 8 bit signed integer addition range

Tags: binary, signed

I have a question from Patterson's computer Organization book.

Here they gave two numbers A and B which are 8 bit signed integer. The values of A and B are 216 and 255 respectively. They are asking to find A+B and A - B and report if there is any overflow/underflow.

Now my doubt is - you cannot even represent 216 in 8 bit signed numbers. The range is [-128,127]. So the question is invalid!!

I would really appreciate if anyone confirms my doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds right. Are you sure the book doesn't say unsigned? There's an errata page at http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs343/errata.php, but this isn't listed. It seems like something a computer professor would have noticed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The question in the book said "Assume A and B are signed 8 bit decimal integers stored in two's complement format".

Answer (score 0):

The question is not invalid at all.  In fact, questions of this type are quite common to ensure you understand overflow/underflow just wrap around the bit representations like when an odometer rolls over to all zeros when the milage gets too high.  Since I am a Computer Science faculty, as well, I'll try to assist without answering the Patterson problem directly.

You are correct to instinctively feel 216 is not representable in a signed 8 bit number, but let's look at how these things actually work.

Say you have a signed 4 bit machine and need to store the number -11.  You might be clever and note that the range of signed 4 bit numbers is [-8,7], so -11 must be impossible.  Not so... First, store 11... that's 0000...0000001011_2 in general, but we must squeeze it into 4 bits, losing all but the low order 4 bits.  So 11 = 1011_2.  At this point you might be saying, "but isn't that a negative number?"  Well, if you have any horses, hold them for a minute.  Now negate 4 bit 11 to get 4 bit -11... 2s comp negation requires flipping all bits and adding 1, so -1011_2 = 0100_2 + 1 = 0101_2.

Ok, you can stop holding your horses now.  It ***is*** true that 0101_2 is actually +5, but might it also be just as good as -11?  Remember your early math days when your teachers told you to check your results?... we can do the same here to feel all warm and cozy about +5 being the same as -11.  For example -11 + 6 = -5, right?  So if we add 6 to 0101_2 and get -5, we should be satisfied with our seemingly out-of-range -11, correct?  Of course! :-)  So let's see... 6 = 0110_2 in 4 bits, now let's add.

```
  0101
+ 0110
------
  1011
```

So what is 1011_2?  It's negative; we can tell because the sign bit (left most bit) is 1.  To find its magnitude, we can just negate it... -1011_2 = 0100_2 + 1 = 0101_2, which to our astonishment is 5, so the original result, 1011_2 is -5, the answer one should have expected.

Maybe we're not convinced this is Ok.  Let's verify -11 is 0101_2 by adding 14.  That should give us a result of 3 because -11 + 14 = 3.  Uh oh... 14 also seems to be out of range, but let's work like a machine and just do what we're told, no matter how stupid it might seem.  +14 is 0000...0001110_2 generally, but we have to squeeze it into 4 bits by losing all but the low order 4 bits.  So +14 in signed 4 bits is 1110_2.  Let's add that to -11...

```
  0101  // -11
+ 1110  // +14
------
 10011 ...but this also needs to get squeezed into 4 bits, so it's 0011
```

Hey, isn't 0011_2 the same thing as +3?  It is!  So it looks like you actually can store numbers that appear outside the obvious range and they can still be used accurately for at least some math.

So hopefully this has given you an idea of how you can approach storing 255 and 216 in a signed 8 bit format without worry.  But I'll leave the detection of overflow/underflow to you :-P

Good luck.